# How to check when a process stopped running?

Tags: command-line, process, logs

I'm trying to figure out when a command I entered stopped executing, for example

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I want information like:

```
started execution at : 12:00
finished execution at : 12:15
```

Comment: Using `time` before any command tells the execution time it took (in minutes and seconds).

Comment: Maybe take a look at the `acct` package, it is used for process accounting, and logs start- and run-time among other info.

Answer (score 2):

Key point that should be understood about processes is that their metadata is not logged by default. You can, however, obtain certain information while process runs.

As has been stated in related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5731234/3701431) in [wlk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731337/3701431), start time can be obtained via `-o` flag to `ps` and `ltime` format specifier:

```
ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd
```

Stop time, however, is not tracked by the system usually, so that's something you'll have to track yourself. Knowing PID of a process, you could poll for that PID existence, and echo the timestamp when it disappears

```
while kill -s 0 $pid ; do : ; sleep 0.25 ; done && date
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207048/3701431

Comment: And how to get starttime if process has already stop'ed ?

Comment: @SorenA That's probably the core of the issue that should be explained. Linux system does not log such information. If a process is running - you can query information about it. Once it exits - its information is gone.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing our own bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=$(date +"%T")

$*                    

finish_time=$(date +"%T")

echo "started execution at : $start_time"
echo "finished execution at : $finish_time"
```

Save the script as `logscript.sh`

Make it executable by using `chmod +x logscript.sh`

You can run 'command' using `./logscript.sh command`

For example, `./logscript.sh sudo apt-get update`

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Check this [site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-read-time-in-shell-script/) for interesting time-display formats.